# AWS Recognizing Faces in a Streaming Video Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I am facing issue while implementing Amazon Rekognition. The error I am getting is:

1. AWSRekognition class, createStreamProcessor API call always through the following error:

> Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSRekognitionErrorDomain Code=7  UserInfo={__type=InvalidParameterException, Logref=aadd2387-8289-44e7-b8f8-d72d52debed3, Message=Input stream limit exceeded for arn:aws:kinesisvideo:eu-west-1:549731499035:stream/FaceRecognitionDemo/1535630649185, Code=InvalidParameterException}”

2. AWSKinesisRecorder class API submitAllRecords API call always through the following error:

> Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSKinesisErrorDomain Code=13  UserInfo={__type=ResourceNotFoundException, message=Stream FaceRecognitionDemo under account 549731499035 not found.}

Due to these issue buffer data not submitted to kinesis video so that stream can start and start searching the face.

Any help appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the problem it is clear that the issue is related to one of the following:

1. Limits Exceeded causing `InvalidParameterException`.
2. Maybe cross-region resource sharing which is not allowed in AWS so you should double check, which means stream processor, kinesis etc all should be in one region.
3. Resources are shared across accounts and permissions are not properly to access the resources from other account. Like, stream preprocessor dosent have permissions to access kinesis stream.

Things to check to fix #1:

- One Kinesis stream can be attached to only one stream preprocessor, and if you will try to violate this i.e. one stream with 2 preprocessor than the similar exception would be thrown.
- Input source and output source both should have 1:1 mapping in stream and preprocessor.